# how to delete data from react crud using node js to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I can't delete values in mongodb using reactjs and node js

- this is my react hooks axios post method send to node js

```
    const deleteUser = id => {
            var data={"id":id}
             axios.post('http://localhost:8010/api/social/deletedata',data)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('response',res);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error block called',error);
            })
            setEditing(false)
            setUsers(users.filter(user => user.id !== id))
            }
```

- this is my node js code

```
     router.post('/deletedata', function(req, res, next) {
          console.log("deleted values are",req.body)
        //var id = req.body;

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          var myId = JSON.parse(req.body.id);
          db.collection('customers').deleteMany({"_id": objectId(myId)}, function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Item deleted');
            db.close();
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: it does not delete value in mongodb. Only show that Id in node js console

Comment: is this message printed? Item deleted. Also could you check is "err" variable has information?

Comment: yes its printed. and err has null value

Comment: Why are you using JSON.parse. Is myId having proper id of the document to be deleted? Also here you have written objectId with small 'o'. It should be capital 'O' as ObjectId. Also are you importing the mongodb ObjectId type because javascript doesnt have a default type as ObjectId.

Comment: if i dont use JSON it give error msg that javascript format is required

Comment: Are you using body-parser middleware? Using body parser allows you to access req.body from within your routes, and use that data

Comment: Yes im using that also

Comment: Is the value in myId variable coming correct? Also have you changed the objectId to ObjectId?

Comment: I think the problem here is that the db is not being specified here. You need to specify the db name. So here the db will be db('myDBName').

Comment: Could you try https://gist.github.com/BretCameron/b150f9ba9fa8432dd0aab39d42b95a77?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the _id as ObjectID, try like this

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');


 router.post('/deletedata', function(req, res, next) {
          console.log("deleted values are",req.body)
        //var id = req.body;

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
          assert.equal(null, err);
          db.collection('customers').deleteMany({"_id": new mongodb.ObjectID(req.body.id)}, 
          function(err, result) {
            assert.equal(null, err);
            console.log('Item deleted');
            db.close();
          });
        });
      });
```